# Hide TextField's cursor when unfocused

Tags: flutter

In flutter, When we edit a `TextField` and close soft-keyboard by touching outside, the cursor of `TextField` is showing and blinking

How can I exit editing mode when unfocused? i.e. keyboard is closed

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far

Comment: call this `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()` to manually unfocus, hiding keyboard doesnt unfocus the field, but unfocussing would

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to keyboard close event via eg. [flutter_keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility) and then call `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()`:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  KeyboardVisibility.onChange.listen((bool visible) {
    if (!visible) FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
  });
}
```

If you already have your own way to detect that user is done with editing the text, then just call `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` -- it will disable the cursor and close the keyboard.

Comment: not working , with latest version